# HtmlUnit with report generator: get Report body after generation

Tags: java, html, birt, htmlunit

I want to use the Java HtmlUnit library to generate a BIRT report in HTML. However, BIRT shows a process bar while the data is loaded from the database and assembled on the page. When I am opening the BIRT report with HtmlUnit, only the page with the process bar is returned but the report content information remains empty. 
The returned HTML page contains a div `<DIV ID="Document" CLASS="birtviewer_document_fragment"></DIV>` which is empty but should be getting filled by the report generator. However, whatever I do, I don't get this "Document" Div filled with data.
I am using the following code:

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    HtmlPage page=null;
    try {
        page = webClient.getPage("https://....");
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60000);
        System.out.println("Waiting 5 secs.....");
        synchronized (page) {
            page.wait(5000);
        }
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DomElement oe = page.getElementById("Document");
    System.out.println(oe.getChildElementCount());
    webClient.close();
```

As output I am always getting 0 for the number of children of the Document div. When I print the HTML source code of the page, I always get the empty Document div.
What am I doing wrong? Could someone please put me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: do you have a public url to reproduce?

Comment: @RBRi Sorry, I checked with my company but I am not allowed to post a public URL to one of our servers. I also searched in the Internet to find a running BIRT example but could not find one. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Maybe the output is created using the animation API. Please have a look at https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/details.html. Maybe you can give the code from Animations based on Window.requestAnimationFrame() after your wait a try.

Comment: I tried using window.animateAnimationsFrames() after webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60000) but the pending frames are 0 and the final result is the same as before :-(

Comment: without a sample it is hard to investigate this

Comment: Pleas open an issue at github and i will try to contact you....

Comment: Thank you for your support. I created an issue #374.